# How to display selected value of enum dropdown list in mvc 5 razor?

Tags: enums, dropdown, selected

How to display selected value of enum dropdown list in mvc 5 razor ?

Comment: Add some code for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

May be this will help you. My enum is ***StatusActiveInactive***

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserStatus", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(StatusActiveInactive), (Model.User.StatusIsActive == true ? StatusActiveInactive.Active : StatusActiveInactive.InActive)), "Select", new {
 @class = "selectpicker show-tick form-control", id = "StatusId"  })
```

With above code I can get list of enum's entity and set it to drop-down list.